# xml parsing for this specific xml

Tags: python, xml

```
    <instance id="activate.v.bnc.00024693" docsrc="BNC">
<answer instance="activate.v.bnc.00024693" senseid="38201"/>
<context>
Do you know what it is ,  and where I can get one ?  We suspect you had seen the Terrex Autospade ,  which is made by Wolf Tools .  It is quite a hefty spade , with bicycle - type handlebars and a sprung lever at the rear , which you step on to <head>activate</head> it . Used correctly ,  you should n't have to bend your back during general digging ,  although it wo n't lift out the soil and put in a barrow if you need to move it !  If gardening tends to give you backache ,  remember to take plenty of rest periods during the day ,  and never try to lift more than you can easily cope with .  
</context>
</instance>
```

I would like to extract all texts inside . This is what I currently have. stuff.text only prints texts before `<head></head>` (ie. Do you know ... step on to), but I don't know how to extract the later half after `</head>` (ie. it . Used ...easily cope with.)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
tree = et.parse(os.getcwd()+"/../data/train.xml")
instance = tree.getroot()

    for stuff in instance:
        if(stuff.tag == "answer"):
            print "the correct answer is %s" % stuff.get('senseid')
        if(stuff.tag == "context"):
            print dir(stuff)
            print stuff.text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using BeautifulSoup is an option, it would be trivial:

```
import bs4
xtxt = '''        <instance id="activate.v.bnc.00024693" docsrc="BNC">
    <answer instance="activate.v.bnc.00024693" senseid="38201"/>
    <context>
    Do you know what it is ,  and where I can get one ?  We suspect you had seen the Terrex Autospade ,  which is made by Wolf Tools .  It is quite a hefty spade , with bicycle - type handlebars and a sprung lever at the rear , which you step on to <head>activate</head> it . Used correctly ,  you should n't have to bend your back during general digging ,  although it wo n't lift out the soil and put in a barrow if you need to move it !  If gardening tends to give you backache ,  remember to take plenty of rest periods during the day ,  and never try to lift more than you can easily cope with .  
    </context>
    </instance>'''
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(xtxt)
print soup.find('context').text
```

gives:

```
Do you know what it is ,  and where I can get one ?  We suspect you had
seen the Terrex Autospade ,  which is made by Wolf Tools .  It is quite 
a hefty spade , with bicycle - type handlebars and a sprung lever at the 
rear , which you step on to activate it . Used correctly ,  you shouldn't 
have to bend your back during general digging ,  although it wo n't lift 
out the soil and put in a barrow if you need to move it !  If gardening 
tends to give you backache ,  remember to take plenty of rest periods 
during the day ,  and never try to lift more than you can easily cope 
with .
```

If you prefere to use ElementTree, you should use `itertext` to process all the text:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
tree = et.parse(os.getcwd()+"/../data/train.xml")
instance = tree.getroot()

    for stuff in instance:
        if(stuff.tag == "answer"):
            print "the correct answer is %s" % stuff.get('senseid')
        if(stuff.tag == "context"):
            print dir(stuff)
            print ''.join(stuff.itertext())
```

If you are sure that your xml file is correct, ElementTree is enough and as it is part of the standard Python library you will have no external dependancy. But if the XML could be ill formed, BeautifulSoup is great at fixing minor errors.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use element serialization. There are two options:

- keep internal `<head></head>`
- return just text without any tags.

In case of serialization with tags the external `<context></context>` tag may be removed manually:

```
# convert element to string and remove <context></context> tag
print(et.tostring(stuff).strip().lstrip('<context>').rstrip('</context>')))
# read only text without any tags
print(et.tostring(stuff, method='text'))
```